# Oracle: Create Trigger on drop user

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle11g

Can a trigger be created on drop user event? if so, how do I write the the trigger - 
*** I want to delete some rows related to that user from a table after drop user ***

"Drop User"

Can you provide an example:

If the user is drop and oracle purge the user's schema objects is there anyway I can select what row of data I want to keep or delete?

So are you saying that a Trigger can not be created on drop user event?

Comment: @codingbiz you cannot delete a user using `delete` statement, db users can only be deleted using the `drop` statement. `delete` is used to delete rows from a database `table`.

Comment: Oh! Now I understand. I was confused by OP's question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can. Assuming you're actually dropping a *user* and not a table:

You're looking for a [system trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99887) as opposed to a schema trigger or a database trigger. You can add these to a large number of [ddl events](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#CIHBDEFD) including `DROP`.

To quote from the documentation:

> Causes the database to fire the trigger whenever a DROP statement
>   removes a database object from the data dictionary.

Your trigger might look something like the following:

```
create or replace trigger tr_drop_user
  before drop on database

begin
   if dbms_standard.dictionary_obj_type = 'USER' then

      insert into logs ( user, object_name )
      values ( sys_context('USERENV','OS_USER') -- OS User doing the dropping
             , dbms_standard.dictionary_obj_name -- name of object being dropped
              );

   end if;
end;
/
```

This uses the [not particularly well documented](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/search?remark=quick_search&word=dbms_standard) `dbms_standard` package to work out what's happening. PSOUG has [better documentation](http://psoug.org/reference/system_events.html), in my opinion.

If you only want to do this for a specific schema rather than for the entire database use `before drop on schema` instead.

---

Just as a little side note I'm not convinced of the need to do this in a trigger. It would be better if you created a package with `drop_user` and `create_user` procedures that do everything you want in one place rather than disguising the logic in a trigger.

Comment: This is very bad advice. Using undocumented features you are basically on your own. In the next version these features might no longer be available and oracle support won't help you either

Comment: @steve, my _advice_ is to not use a trigger and create a package instead. I also answered the question; just because something isn't necessarily the best way of doing something doesn't mean that the OP won't actually need an answer. In saying there's a better way I can also draw their attention to other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create `triggers` on statements (`DDL` or `DML`, *except on some system level statements found [here](http://psoug.org/reference/system_trigger.html)*). Triggers can only be created on `tables`on a database. In your question, [`drop user <username>;`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_9008.htm) is a statement.

I quote:

> Use the DROP USER statement to remove a database user and optionally
>   remove the user's objects.
>
> When you drop a user, Oracle Database also purges all of that user's
>   schema objects from the recycle bin.

Note- in view of confusion of whether you are trying to actually `drop` a `user` or trying to `drop` a custom table named `user`, below are the statements you would use.

To drop a DB user - `drop user username [cascade];`

To drop a table named user - `drop table user [cascade constraints];`

the options in `[ ]` are optional.

Comment: Actually, there are a bunch of system event triggers now as well. Check out the [PSOUG](http://psoug.org/reference/system_trigger.html) site.

Comment: Yes, but there are a limited number of those and I don't see one that can be used for a user statement like `drop`, `delete`.

Comment: Yup, I agree. There are DML triggers and System triggers, neither of which useful for a DROP USER command. Of course, it is not quite clear whether the op actually means DROP USER or whether they are dealing with a custom "USER" table and deleting a record out of there.

Comment: Either way, there no way to create a trigger on `drop user` or `drop table` (Although it would be a huge tool for DBAs).

Comment: You're completely wrong. You can create database level, system level and schema level triggers on pretty much [any event you care to name](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm).

Comment: @Ben can you give me an example of a trigger that would fire on `drop user` statement. This is new to me. The only db system events on which a trigger is possible (as per your link) are- `AFTER STARTUP`,`BEFORE SHUTDOWN`, `AFTER DB_ROLE_CHANGE`,`AFTER SERVERERROR`,`AFTER LOGON`,`BEFORE LOGOFF`,`AFTER SUSPEND`. Can you show me an example of - `AFTER DROP` or `BEFORE DROP`?

Comment: @Annjawn, my answer :-), also this [ask tom article](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:13273199418308); I'd recommend doing it with tables rather than users though. You're talking about database triggers there, not system triggers.

Comment: Hmm...that's a db trigger. I don't think the OP should be creating DB triggers (or schema triggers), or it may need sys privs. Also, do you think that the trigger you wrote in your answer will work for `on schema` instead of `on database` because technically `schema` is a db `user` (just wondering).

Comment: I double checked I wasn't wrong with a schema level trigger and dropping a table. Try it foe.yourself! As I say I wouldn't do this, I'd put it in a package.